# Logging all Django deprecation warnings

Tags: python, django, logging

Is it possible to log deprecation warnings in Django to a lot file or something similar? I'm unsure how to setup a filter for something like this.

Edit: The answer below does not answer this question whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're on a linux machine, try this:

```
./manage.py runserver 2> foo.txt
```

This will redirect the standard error stream to the file foo.txt

Deprecation errors go to standard error, so this should take care of you.

If you already have a log that you want to append to, of course it would be the usual append notation:

```
./manage.py runserver 2>> foo.txt
```

If you're using django 1.11, you'd need to tell python to display warnings. The following should work:

```
python -Wd manage.py runserver 2>> foo.txt
```

(haven't had a chance to try this, but it should work)

You might want to create an alias for this if you find it useful and want to do it often.

Comment: Note that deprecation warnings are no longer loud by default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#deprecating-warnings-are-no-longer-loud-by-default

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - we're still on 1.8, so I hadn't come across that. Amending my answer.

Comment: Deprecation warnings only come up as they occur. Which means if you use a function on one end of the site it won't appear until you access it. The foo.txt would be filled with normal GET logs. I'm looking for a way to use DJangos built In logging method